# Yii2 generate CRUD with MSSQL

Tags: yii2, crud, yii2-advanced-app, gii

I want to know how we can generate CRUD operations of MSSQL with Gii. I have already added the `MSSQL` credentials in my config section. But when I try to generate it via Gii I cant see any tables of MSSQL.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can not generate table via GII. First you have to create table on your database. Then you can make model, Controller & views using gii.

Comment: @RaihanUddin I know this but Is there any other way of doing this? Like can we do it manually?

Comment: check this link: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-migrations.
first create migration of the table & then migrate it. After migrate go to gii to create CRUD operation

Comment: @RaihanUddin how to do the migration after creating it?